# Robust linear interpolation

Tags: geometry, precision

Given two segment endpoints A and B (in two dimensions), I would like to perform linear interpolation based on a value t, i.e.:

```
C = A + t(B-A)
```

In the ideal world, A, B and C should be collinear. However, we are operating with limited floating-point here, so there will be small deviations. To work around numerical issues with other operations I am using robust adaptive routines originally created by Jonathan Shewchuk. In particular, Shewchuk implements an orientation function `orient2d` that uses adaptive precision to exactly test the orientation of three points.

Here my question: is there a known procedure how the interpolation can be computed using the floating-point math, so that it lies exactly on the line between A and B? Here, I care less about the accuracy of the interpolation itself and more about the resulting collinearity. In another terms, its ok if C is shifted around a bit as long as collinearity is satisfied.

Comment: if collinearity is really more important than accuray, let C= A. Otherwise, drop the idea.

Comment: I would assume that you need more precision for *C* to make this work. If the coordinates of *A* and *B* are native doubles, one can probably represent the coordinates of a suitable *C* as a pair of doubles per coordinate. But that would mean your space requirements will grow exponentially as you use such points as the input of another interpolation step.

Comment: why not compute `C=A+t.(B-A)` and then search region around `C` selecting the best `C` for which `dot(C-A,B-A)/(|C-A|.|B-A|)` is closet to one. You can also try `cross(C-A,B-A)` is minimal (area of triangle is minimal). For this computation you can use 2 doubles per value to enhance precision without the need of having those for all the points ...

Comment: @Spektre, that was my idea, to use nextafter() to search around C until orient(A, C', B) ==0. But it will probably be very slow, plus I am sure that there are a number of surprise edge cases. I am afraid that Yves's post might be spot on. I was just wondering whether there are some papers that deal with this issue (because most I have read just dismiss such questions from the onset).

Comment: @MrMobster I don't think it would be too slow. You do not have to search a big area just a circle/square around C with size of few `ulp` of the coordinates. To boost precision you can also use relative coordinates so point `(0,0,0)` is `A,B` or `(A+B)/2` you would be surprised how much it can do see [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) I do not see any edge cases at all but yes you can not expect full match only the best fit

Comment: @MrMobster btw you can try to do a modified integer DDA on fixed point `floats` (without changing their exponent) to achieve the `ulp` precision. it uses just `+,-,<` but that will need `for` loop so it would be slower `O(|AC|)`

Comment: @MrMobster did you manage to find a good solution to this problem? :)

Comment: @AMA Kind of. I decided to simply split AB into AC and BC, which approximate the original AB. The main issue with this is that it does change the angles a little bit and so if you have a lot of segments in a cramped area, the newly created segments may end up intersection their neighbours. I deal with this by imposing a minimal limit on angles of segments that share an endpoint. Works quite well and is still very fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The bad news

The request can't be satisfied. There are values of `A` and `B` for which there is NO value of `t` other than 0 and 1 for which `lerp(A, B, t)` is a float.

A trivial example in single precision is `x1 = 12345678.f` and `x2 = 12345679.f`. Regardless of the values of `y1` and `y2`, the required result must have an `x` component between `12345678.f` and `12345679.f`, and there's no single-precision float between these two.

#### The (sorta) good news

The exact interpolated value, however, can be represented as the sum of 5 floating-point values (vectors in the case of 2D): one for the formula's result, one for the error in each operation [1] and one for multiplying the error by `t`. I'm not sure if that will be useful to you. Here's a 1D C version of the algorithm in single precision that uses fused multiply-add to calculate the product error, for simplicity:

```
#include <math.h>

float exact_sum(float a, float b, float *err)
{
    float sum = a + b;
    float z = sum - a;
    *err = a - (sum - z) + (b - z);
    return sum;
}

float exact_mul(float a, float b, float *err)
{
    float prod = a * b;
    *err = fmaf(a, b, -prod);
    return prod;
}

float exact_lerp(float A, float B, float t,
                 float *err1, float *err2, float *err3, float *err4)
{
    float diff = exact_sum(B, -A, err1);
    float prod = exact_mul(diff, t, err2);
    *err1 = exact_mul(*err1, t, err4);
    return exact_sum(A, prod, err3);
}
```

In order for this algorithm to work, operations need to conform to IEEE-754 semantics in round-to-nearest mode. That's not guaranteed by the C standard, but the GNU *gcc* compiler can be instructed to do so, at least in processors supporting SSE2 [2][3].

It is guaranteed that the arithmetic addition of `(result + err1 + err2 + err3 + err4)` will be equal to the desired result; however, there is no guarantee that the floating-point addition of these quantities will be exact.

To use the above example, `exact_lerp(12345678.f, 12345679.f, 0.300000011920928955078125f, &err1, &err2, &err3, &err4)` returns a result of `12345678.f` and `err1`, `err2`, `err3` and `err4` are `0.0f`, `0.0f`, `0.300000011920928955078125f` and `0.0f` respectively. Indeed, the correct result is 12345678.300000011920928955078125 which can't be represented as a single-precision float.

A more convoluted example: `exact_lerp(0.23456789553165435791015625f, 7.345678806304931640625f, 0.300000011920928955078125f, &err1, &err2, &err3, &err4)` returns `2.3679010868072509765625f` and the errors are `6.7055225372314453125e-08f`, `8.4771045294473879039287567138671875e-08f`, `1.490116119384765625e-08f` and `2.66453525910037569701671600341796875e-15f`. These numbers add up to the exact result, which is 2.36790125353468550173374751466326415538787841796875 and can't be exactly stored in a single-precision float.

All numbers in the examples above are written using their exact values, rather than a number that approximates to them. For example, 0.3 can't be represented exactly as a single-precision float; the closest one has an exact value of 0.300000011920928955078125 which is the one I've used.

It might be possible that if you calculate `err1 + err2 + err3 + err4 + result` (in that order), you get an approximation that is considered collinear in your use case. Perhaps worth a try.

#### References

- [1] Graillat, Stef (2007). [*Accurate Floating Point Product and Exponentiation.*](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/IEEE-TC-prod.pdf)
- [2] [Enabling strict floating point mode in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295861/enabling-strict-floating-point-mode-in-gcc)
- [3] [Semantics of Floating Point Math in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath)